# How can i prevent a logged in user to delete post by others users?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a problem, I can not prevent a logged in user to delete post by others users? 
In my code now, I can delete all users posts, but I want to be able to only delete my posts (the logged
in user posts).
Can somebody help me in the right direction on how to do that?

```
<div class="deletebtn"><a href="../delete/delete.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"class=\"icon-2 info-tooltip\">Delete post</a></div>



$id=$_GET['id'];

$sql="DELETE FROM shouts WHERE id='$id'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

if($result)
{
    echo('<div class="deletedpost">You have deleted a post. <a href="../pages/content.php">Tillbaka till Bloggen</a></div>');
}
else 
{
    echo "Something went wrong";
}
mysql_close();
```

Im using a href in one file, linking to another file where a use Sql code.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: you need a foreign key in your shouts table to tie posts to certain users

Comment: @PeeHaa Thanks, Im gonna take a look on that.

Comment: To add to @PeeHaa: What if I go to the URL `delete.php?id=%27%3BDROP%20TABLE%20shouts%3B//`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this via  `session`

check if user is logged in or not. if logged in then delete the post

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
    //delete post
}
```

Store `userId` in your table and update your delete query like this...

```
$sql="DELETE FROM shouts WHERE id='$id' and userId = '$_SESSION[user]'";
```

Comment: Thanks, but Im using session now but your code does not work, I still can delete all posts.

Comment: @BrunoChavez store user id in table. like if you add Item then store your user id and then update your delete query as in my answer

Comment: create column `userId` in your `shouts` table. then just store UserId in it. like if you added something then store your ID. then specify your session id in delete query. this will work

Comment: I made a column userid in my shouts tabel, and I used your sql code, but Its not working... Now I can not delete any post.

Comment: show me your code, also show me the data which you have inserted in your column `userId`

Comment: <?php
 if(isset($_SESSION['userName']))
 {
  $id=$_GET['id'];
  
  //$sql="DELETE FROM shouts WHERE id='$id'";
  $sql="DELETE FROM shouts WHERE id='$id' and userId = '$_SESSION[userName]'";
  $result=mysql_query($sql);
  
  if($result)
  {
   echo('<div class="deletedpost">You deletyed the post. <a href="../pages/content.php">Back to the blog</a></div>');
  }
  else 
  {
   echo "something wrongt";
  }
  mysql_close();
 } 
?>

Comment: CREATE TABLE `shouts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `lund` varchar(70) NOT NULL,
  `LundaBlogg` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL,
  `likes` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `post` text NOT NULL,
  `ipaddress` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `userId` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `email` (`email`),
  KEY `lund` (`lund`),
  KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=20 ;

Comment: @BrunoChavez it seems you have stored `User Name` in your session and you are deleting the record by checking `User Name = User Id`. this will not work... so you must have to store `User Id` in `Session` and then in your query replace code `userId=$_SESSION['userId']`

Comment: and UserId must be int not varchar

Comment: I changed UserId to int, and I stored userId in a session, but its not working...

Comment: what you are stored in UserId field in table? and what is you session user id?

Comment: and make sure the delete query is in currect format like `$sql="DELETE FROM shouts WHERE id='".$id."' and userId =" .$_SESSION['userId'];`

Comment: My userId field is showing 0. And I tried to save userId in a session like this $_SESSION['userId'];

Comment: in which table all username are stored?

Comment: I am aking about userId. where you stored your username?

Comment: I have admin_usr_name in my tbladmin tabel, and not in shouts tabel.

Comment: this will be your delete query now. `$sql="DELETE FROM shouts WHERE id='".$id."' and userName = '".$_SESSION['username']."'";` also change `userId` to `userName` in your `shout` table. `int` to `varchar`. insert your username for testing. this will works

Comment: Not working, Its says "Something went wrong". In your sql what do you mean with userName with a big N and why is it ".$_SESSION['username']." with a small N. I really dont understand whats going on now, but thanks for the help...

Comment: `userName` is a field in table and `$_SESSION[username]` is your session variable

Comment: we are comparing value of `session` with table value. if match it will delete the record. if other will do this, it will not work because other user have different username. It's very simple.

Comment: Its not working. I made your changes, but I wonder what do you mean with "insert your username for testing."

Comment: insert your username means. Insert username of yours in `userName` field. and try to delete that record for testing.

Comment: Ok, when Im inserting my logged in username SuperAdmin Its working, but do I have to do that with every post?

Comment: yah you can do it with everypost. when user post you just store its username and then only he can delete.

Comment: suppose I am user. my username is `sumit`. so when I add Item, store my record with username in your `shout` table. like `id=17, username=sumit`. it means when someone other try to delete, it will not work because his username is different then me.

Comment: Ok, so when somebody posting a new post, I have to do a sql that also sets username in my shouts tabel?

Comment: yah. and then he/she only can delete the post

Comment: Im really really sorry Sumit, It is working when I inserted my logged in username SuperAdmin under userName field in shouts tabel. Now I have to figure out how my sql should look like when a user post a shout on my blog.

Comment: Many thanks for the help Sumit.B, now Im gonna figure out how my sql should look like when a user post a shout on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the logged in user is the owner for the particular post before deleting.

Write a select query with post id and owner id. If it returns true allow him to delete the post otherwise do not allow.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have a $_SESSION['id'] of sorts?
And you do have that user id associated in shouts table, so you know who's shout is it right?

`DELETE FROM shouts WHERE id='$id' AND user_id='$_SESSION['id']'`

You should treatthe inputs though.

Comment: Catita Thanks, but what is user_id='$_SESSION['id']'

Answer (score 0):

use this kind of query, here it will delete only logged in user's post.

```
$sql="DELETE FROM shouts WHERE id='$id' and user_id = '$loggedin_session_id'";
```

Comment: Thanks, but what is user_id = '$loggedin_session_id'"

Comment: @BrunoChavez `$loggedin_session_id` is your user id of loggedin user

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that upon the user signing up, you assign them a unique id (or let the database do it with auto increment) and save it in the database. Then, whenever they log in, you can pull that user_id from the database and store it in a session variable. When shouts are created, you store the user_id of the person who created the shout alongside the shout itself in the shouts table of the database. When a user attempts to delete a shout, you first check to make sure that that shout belongs to them before allowing them to delete it.

An example:

```
<?php

//when user logs in
$email = 'example@example.com';
$password = 'default';
$sql = "SELECT id FROM user_table WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'] //'id' is the user's id; assign it to the session variable

//user creates the shout
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id']; //get the user_id from the logged-in user
$shout = $_POST['shout'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO shout_table (user_id, shout) VALUES ('$user_id','$shout')"; //store user id alongside the shout for future queries
mysql_query($sql);

//user about to delete the shout
$id = $_GET['id'];
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
//the sql to check in the shout_table to see if the shout they are deleting belongs to them
$sql = "SELECT * FROM shout_table WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND id = '$id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

if ($row)
{
    //everything is alright; this user can delete the shout, so prepare the DELETE query to do so
}
else
{
    //the user is not allowed to delete the shout because it's not theirs; tell them so with an echo or whatever you're using for error handling
}

?>
```

The example above is rife with SQL injections. Validate and sanitize, of course. As well, **mysql_query functions will be deprecated as of PHP 5.5**, so get in the hang of using [mysqli_query functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead. Better yet, see if you can use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php). :)